# TLS fails at aws ec2: 30592, MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_FATAL_ALERT_MESSAGE

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, websocket, micropython

I have a public WebSocket server which is running right now and I have hundreds of embedded devices connect to it.

I want to move my server to amazon, so I made an EC2 instance and installed my software on it.

When I try to connect from a browser the connection is successful, however when testing with an embedded device I get the error from the title:

```
(-30592, 'MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_FATAL_ALERT_MESSAGE')
```

The devices are Raspberry Pico W's and are running an unstable micropython version (v1.19.1 2022-09-26), which I can not change unfortunately.

Here is the offending code:

```
import usocket as socket
import ussl

uri = urlparse("wss://...")
assert uri

sock = socket.socket()

# allow 30 seconds for initial ws connection
sock.settimeout(30)

addr = socket.getaddrinfo(uri.hostname, uri.port)
sock.connect(addr[0][4])

if uri.protocol == 'wss':
    try:
        sock = ussl.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=uri.hostname)
    except Exception as e:
        sock.close()
        print(e)
```

I installed the WebSocket server software locally and had my embedded device connect to it on my local network (with a self signed cert), so I'm inclined to believe the error has something to do with the way I've set it up on amazon.

So far I've got 2 ideas on where the problem might be:

1. I've read that amazon is dropping support for TLS < 1.2, honestly I kind of think that should not relate to my instance but who knows...
2. I'm not aware of how traffic is getting routed through AWS and how it reaches my EC2 instance, where the server is running, possibly TLS is breaking somewhere along the way.

I'd be very thankful if someone with more AWS experience can help out.

Answer (score 0):

By law, I spend 2 days banging my head against the wall, then as soon as I post a question I find the solution.

Apparently, I got issued an ECDSA cert on my new machine, and it seems like ECDSA support was added in Micropython v1.20.0

All I had to do was revert to RSA, which using `certbot` can not be any easier:

```
certbot certonly --key-type rsa
```

Initially I decided to delete the question as this is a highly specific case that probably nobody else will fall into, but in case anyone does, here it is.